# Offset Idea in Data Windowing(Time Series)

Tags: tensorflow

In a [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) about Time Series. I am interesting to the [Data Windowing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing) idea.

As my understanding, the Offset is the delay time between windows. But it is not enough make sense to me. How to use it in real project?

Do you have any experience in real situation using this parameter?

Comment: Here is an example of tf.data.Dataset.window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70432811/csv-table-row-as-label-for-previous-several-rows/70433365#70433365

Comment: @AloneTogether and with Offset in real situation?